# How to check if a process or thread is alive or not given their IDs in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, process, cross-platform

Given a process or thread ID, how to write a C++ function to check if it is alive or not. I'd like to implement this on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: You need to provide a precise definition of what "alive" is ( killed? suspended? never existed? )

Comment: @JosephH I mean the process is terminated.

Comment: Note that doing this is a little bit risky... there's always a small possibility that process ID #x terminated, and then the process ID was re-used by the OS and handed out to a different process.  OS's typically try to avoid using process ID numbers for as long as possible for this reason, but eventually the numbers do wrap, and you run the risk of thinking "your process" is running when it's really some other unrelated process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not willing to add an extra library dependency to your project, you could wrap system-specific code using pre-processor directives (e.g: `#ifdef _WIN32`).

### Windows

- [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) + [GetExitCodeProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [OpenThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684335%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) + [GetExitCodeThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683190%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

The GetExitCode* functions return `STILL_ACTIVE` if they succeed and the process or thread still exists.

### Linux

- [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill) - Send the null signal (0) to check whether the pid is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to decide first if you are checking for a process or a thread. These two have very different semantics. For processes, try the unofficial [Boost.Process](http://www.netbsd.org/~jmmv/process/). For threads, [Boost.Threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread.html).

Answer (score 0):

Telling if a process ID or thread ID is alive is two different questions.

Thread IDs are easier - They are a part of the process - and therefore the process should know that it has created them and can check if they are current.

Process IDs is a different question - A new process could be created after the previous onw has died with the same ID.

A good solution to this is if you have a family of co-operating processes. You can name them and use the name or shared memory instead. I recommend the latter.

Comment: I think the OP wants to query threads from other processes either.