# Check if thread is alive in Windows

Tags: windows, multithreading

I recently tried to write a code to check if a thread in Windows is alive or not. I searched this forum and found discussions like: [How to check if a process or thread is alive or not given their IDs in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083847/how-to-check-if-a-process-or-thread-is-alive-or-not-given-their-ids-in-c).

I understand I can use OpenThread API. However it doesn't seem to work in my code as follows.

```
DWORD WINAPI myThread( LPVOID lpParam )
{
    cout<<"child thread"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    DWORD  lTldID = 0;
    HANDLE lTldHD = CreateThread(NULL, 0, myThread, 0, 0, &lTldID);

    WaitForSingleObject(lTldHD, INFINITE);
    HANDLE lHD = OpenThread(0x0040, FALSE, lTldID);
    return 1;
}
```

I expect that the HANDLE lHD should be NULL since the thread 'myThread' should have finished at the time of calling OpenThread(). However, I always got NOT NULL values like 0x00000068. I don't know why this happened. Any idea?

Thanks,
Xiaomo

Comment: No, the handle will not be null since you didn't release the other handle yet.  The thread object itself still exists, it will only disappear when you close all handles.  After which you should *never* use the thread id again.  What problem you are really trying to solve is very unclear.

Comment: Thankfully, the handle is not null. This means you can `WaitForSingleObject` on it. Which is exactly what you want to do (though with zero timeout, not infinite). If you get `WAIT_TIMEOUT`, the thread is alive, if you get `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, it's not.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks a lot for the reply. My goal is to check if a thread crashed or finished its execution.

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL WINAPI GetExitCodeThread(
  _In_  HANDLE  hThread,
  _Out_ LPDWORD lpExitCode
);
```

This function returns immediately. If the specified thread has not terminated and the function succeeds, the status returned is `STILL_ACTIVE`.